# Partition have size of img after using "dd" to install

Tags: linux, mount, partition, disk-image, lfs

I have a partition of size 50GB and made image via some disk tool (through GUI). But it had size of entire partition (50GB).

Then I resized that image to 8.7GB:

```
e2fsck -f -y xxx.img
resize2fs -M xxx.img
```

Then I mounted it on partition with size 15GB:

```
dd if=myIMG.img of=/dev/sda13
```

But problem is that when I open system monitor it keeps showing me that system max size is 8.3GB instead of 14GB.

And in "lsblk" i can see that partition have 14GB

I don't know how to fix it. Probably I did any stupid mistake but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: WHat is the exact `dd` command?

Comment: @RomeoNinov dd if=/dev/sda13 of=/pathToImg/myImg.img

Comment: And how did you mount it? Did you copy with dd to new disk?

Comment: I created that partition with cfdisk. Then i just used that command. Thats all nothing else. (i am still new in this things).

Comment: @RomeoNinov And sorry for mistake command for mounting was dd if=myIMG.img of=/dev/sda13 not as i wrote earlier in comment.

Comment: Did you check what was the size of this partition `/dev/sda13`? Is it 15GB?

Comment: @RomeoNinov *14. Yes with lsblk and other utilities its showing me 14 as i created it with cfdisk. Gparted shows me 14 too.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ou gparted shows that 5.91GB is unallocated. Thats the problem.

Comment: `dd` is not for mounting partitions, it duplicates disc! So if you have `/dev/sda` disc, your command just wiped out content of partition 13.

Comment: What exactly is your intention? You want to create simply partition on `/dev/sda` disc? Or you want some virtual disc image?

Comment: Everything works now thanks. Well i just wanted to move/copy image to partition /dev/sda13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mistakes so far, you've just missing the last step!

You've now written an image of a filesystem sized 8.7GB to a partition sized 15G. The last step would be to extend the filesystem size again to take up the entire partition:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda13
```

With modern versions of ext2/3/4 filesystems, you can do this even if the filesystem is already mounted.